# EmberJS: Displaying an Edit/Create form without having to transition to a new URL?

Tags: ember.js, routes, components, ember-router

I have a simple app. In the app, there is a 'stack' resource that loads in another resource, called 'card', and in turn, the 'card' resource has CRUD routes, in effect:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
     this.resource('stack', {path:'/stack'},function(){
              this.resource('card',{path:'/card'},function(){
                         this.route('edit',{path:'/edit'}); // for simplicity, let's only assume the edit operation for this
              });
     });
});
```

The Stack route actually loads the 'Cards' model, something like this:

```
App.StackRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
         model:function(){
             return this.store.find('cards');
         }

});
```

Each of the above works fine, rendering at the URLs as expected. However, I don't wish to have separate URLs for the CRUD operations since it doesn't gel well with the flow of my app and is actually counterintuitive to me to transition into a separate URL. **I want to be able to view, edit and delete the 'card' model all from within the 'stack' model in itself**. Ember, however, doesn't seem to provide this kind of an alternative, almost requiring me to adhere to its ways.

Does anybody have a solution to this? The only other possibility I could think of was to use **'Ember components'**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can just modify the current template based on an editing property.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uwENUbeh/3/edit

Answer (score 1):

You can fine tune editing for individual cards.
[jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uwENUbeh/4/edit)